# Android class vs this

Tags: java, android, class, this, listener

https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-android-wikipedia/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/wikipedia/bridge/CommunicationBridge.java#L26

I was reading the source code of the wiki android app linked above. I stumbled upon this block of code in the constructor of CommunicationBridge class.

```
    this.addListener("DOMLoaded", (messageType, messagePayload) -> {
        isDOMReady = true;
        for (String jsString : pendingJSMessages) {
            CommunicationBridge.this.webView.loadUrl(jsString);
        }
    });
```

I know the more of the code has to be viewed to understand this but I am a little bit confused about:

1.) in the for each statement we are using pendingJSMessages which is a variable defined earlier in the code (an instance variable). And we are accessing here without using this or CommunicationBridge.this so...

2.) why use CommunicationBridge.this.webView.loadUrl() instead of this.webView.loadUrl()? Whats the difference here.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1.) `(x, y) -> {}` is a syntax of java 8 lambda expressions. It can be used in functional programming pattern. Simple alternative of it Anonymous inner class. More information & documentation could be found on [Lambda quick start](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).

2.) In case of nested objects `this` keyword referred to nearest inner object. To refer to the outer objects in hierarchy you have to use this type of syntax.

For example you have two objects: outer object ob1 of class A, inner object ob2 of class B. Now when you use `this` in side ob2 (from method or other execution sequence) refers to the object ob2 by default. To refer to the outer object ob1 from inner object ob1 class A you can use `A.this`.

This can be used in multilevel hierarchy as well as anonymous class & lambda expressions as they are essentially inner classes.